# Draw Text with FreeType (DirectX 11)

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, freetype

So I would like to draw text with FreeType (on DirectX 11). The problem is that I don't really understand how to create the my_draw_bitmap function (I follow [this tutorial](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html#section-1)).

I get all the glyphs then convert them to bitmap, but I don't see how to convert an FT_Bitmap* to a ID3D11Texture2D* (this would - *in theory* - allow me to render a text)

Here is my code :

**FontLoader.cpp**

```
    void FontLoader::RenderText(ID3D11Device* p_device, Text* p_text, Math::Vec2 p_position)
    {
    const char* text = p_text->GetText();

    FT_Face face = p_text->GetFont()->GetFace();
    FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph;

    Math::Vec2 pen = p_position;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(text); ++i)
    {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, text[i], FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            continue;

        // draw to our target surface
        CreateTextureFromBitmap(p_device, &slot->bitmap, Math::Vec2((float)slot->bitmap_left, (float)slot->bitmap_top));

        // Increment pen position
        pen._x += slot->advance.x >> 6;
    }
}

ID3D11Texture2D* FontLoader::CreateTextureFromBitmap(ID3D11Device* p_device, FT_Bitmap* p_bitmap, Math::Vec2 p_position)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    textureDesc.Width = p_bitmap->width;
    textureDesc.Height = p_bitmap->pitch;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    ID3D11Texture2D *texture2D = NULL;
    // don't know how and when to use p_bitmap
    p_device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &texture2D);

    return texture2D;
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You need to supply second parameter when calling `CreateTexture2D`, that is `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA` containing pointer to buffer with FT bitmap data. Note that you may need to copy FT Bitmap data to intermediate buffer. `textureDesc.Height = p_bitmap->pitch;` is wrong, because `pitch` is not height.

Comment: I changed a few things, but now when I try to draw a text, the last letter is drawn 4 times... Here is my code [link](https://pastebin.com/wqPST7h3)

Comment: And here is the result [link](https://pasteboard.co/Hj1ccu2.png)

Comment: I finally managed to fix it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149962/freetype-generates-multiple-textures) is my solution if anyone is interested